# Generating details / summary tree from PHP array that contains associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

[image: details-summary]

I am trying to generate a HTML5 details / summary tree using a foreach loop with the following array that contains associative arrays. I am new to working with arrays and I am unsure how to access the correct part of the array to display the industry or the job. Please see the code and comments below.

I am also unsure if I need two foreach loops or if one will do the job. I could potentially make all the elements associative too (as that would make them easier to call) but I am still learning how to do this by trial and error.

I don't yet want to render "Tasks", "Knowledge", "Skills" etc. This will be done on another page.

All help is much appreciated.

```
$indus['agriculture'] = [
    "Picking and Packing" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Farm Worker" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Agricultural Equipment Operator" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]    
    ],
];

$indus['construction'] = [
    "Picking and Packing" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Farm Worker" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Agricultural Equipment Operator" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
    ],
    "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
];

$array_keys = array_keys($indus);

foreach($array_keys as $key)
{
    echo '<details class="details">';

    echo '<summary>';
    echo "{$indus[$key]}"; //this should be the industry
    echo '</summary>';


    echo '<summary>';
    echo "{$indus[$key]}"; //this should be the job
    echo '</summary> ';

    echo '</details>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need embeded `foreach`s to do this task. Note that [`foreach()`](https://php.net/foreach) can also use the keys.

Example: ([demo](https://3v4l.org/bRI27))

```
// loop around `$indus`:
foreach ($indus as $indusName => $indusData)
{
    echo $indusName . "\n";

    // loop around `$indus` jobs:
    foreach ($indusData as $jobName => $jobData)
    {
        echo '* ' . $jobName . "\n";
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
agriculture
* Picking and Packing
* Farm Worker
* Agricultural Equipment Operator
construction
* Picking and Packing
* Farm Worker
* Agricultural Equipment Operator
* data-code
```

Of course, you could add your HTML tags (`<details>` and `<summary>`) as needed.

Comment: That works thank you. I didn't know you could use the object operator => with foreach. This is very neat.

Comment: I need to confess that I don't completely understand how the solution works.
What is  ($indus as $indusName => $indusData) doing?

Comment: See [this example](https://3v4l.org/nucAq) or [this example](https://3v4l.org/o6o5N). `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` will loop around the `$array` and hold `$key` and `$value` for each iteration. See also [this example](https://3v4l.org/ksY2q).

Comment: So the code in your previous comment will loop over `$indus` and will hold `$indusName` ("agriculture", "construction", ...). `$indusData` will contain the content of the current key (another associative array `["Picking and Packing"=>[...]]`.